# SQL change the specific row

Tags: sql, t-sql

In my table below, i want to change the placement of specific row.

For example,

```
ID Name   Count
1  X      50
2  Y      30
3  other  25
4  Z      20
```

It is DESC ordered and i would like to see X,Y,Z orderly. Also, in total, 'other' should be counted. In other words, count should be 125.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: for example for top 3; X-Y-Z should be viewed. However, in total count, all 4 should be counted.

Comment: What your expected result should look alike?

Comment: for top 3;

ID Name   Count
1  X      50
2  Y      30
3  Z     20

Comment: question is unclear. add your expected output like you provided current output.

Comment: what is your logic for selecting other for sum and remaining rows will have same value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use union all and add last row to the end.
Something like this:

```
select id, name,count from table where name<>other 
union all 
select 4 as id, "other"as name, 135 as count from table
order by 1
```

or if you want to sum it

```
select id, name,count from table where name<>other 
union all 
select 4 as id, 'other' as name, sum(count) as count from table
order by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put some logic in the `order by` clause:

```
select  id, name, count
from    table
order by case when id <> 3 then 1 else 2 end, id
```

This way, the first ordering criteria is "rows X, Y, Z first, then the other ones", then you order the groups the way you want, in your case either by id or by name will work.

You can find a working example [here](https://rextester.com/DAHJJ43230)

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS :

```
SELECT ID,
       Name,
       CASE
          WHEN Name = 'OTHER' THEN (SELECT SUM (COUNT) FROM YOUR_TABLE)
          ELSE SUM (COUNT)
       END
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Name DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `union all` may be the simplest approach, but like this:

```
select id, name, count
from ((select id, name, count, 1 as ord
       from t
       where name in ('X', 'Y', 'Z')
      ) union all
      (select 4, 'other', sum(count), 2 as ord
       from t
      ) 
     ) t
order by ord, name;
```